# Upgrading TFS 2010 to 2012 Update 1 / Error from readiness check TF400129: Verifying that the team project collection has space for new system fields

Tags: tfs, upgrade, argumentexception

I am upgrading TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 Update 1. SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 sits on the same server box. Currently we have three project collections with 1-2 projects in each collection using lightly modified Scrum and Agile templates.

During Readiness check following error is reported:

TF400129: Error from readiness check: Verifying that the team project collection has space for new system fields

Here is the excerpt from the log file:

```
[Info   @08:50:44.021] +-+-+-+-+-| Verifying that the team project collection has space for new system fields |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @08:50:44.021] Starting Node: VUPFLDLMT
[Info   @08:50:44.021] NodePath : VINPUTS/Progress/Conditional/VPCUPGRADE/VCOLLECTIONSREACHABLE/VUPFLDLMT
[Info   @08:50:44.021] Getting Reachable Collections
[Info   @08:50:44.021] Reachable collections found: 2
[Error  @08:50:44.131] System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: serviceLevel
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.TFCommonUtil.CheckStringForNullOrEmpty(String stringVar, String stringVarName, Boolean trim)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServiceLevel..ctor(String serviceLevel)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.VerifyFieldLimitNotExceededInAllTpcs.GetNewFieldCount(String connectionString)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.VerifyFieldLimitNotExceededInAllTpcs.Run(ActivityContext context)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Engine.AdminNode.RunNode()
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Engine.AdminNode.Run(String& message, Boolean& continueOnError)
[Error  @08:50:44.131] Unhandled message not defined for task VUPFLDLMT:Verifying that the team project collection has space for new system fields
[Error  @08:50:44.131] TF400129: Error from readiness check: Verifying that the team project collection has space for new system fields
[Info   @08:50:44.131] Completed VerifyFieldLimitNotExceededInAllTpcs: Error
```

Comment: How "lightly" has the templates been modified ?

Comment: We have added less than five fields to Product Backlog Item template plus some minor modifications to the PBI workflow. As I can recall, we have added one more state before Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason one of our project collections was left in Install stata. Extended property TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL_TO was set to TFS2010.RTM but there was no TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL property defined in the database. We still can't figure out how project collection was left in the Install state in the first place.

Fortunately, we used broken collection as a playground so we can safely delete it since it does not contain any important data. Once we deleted probelmatic collection using TfsConfig tool we were able to perform upgrade to TFS 2012 Update 1 without any validation errors.

```
TfsConfig.exe delete {CollectionName}
```

If you run to the similar issue check SQL Server dababase extended properties using the following query to verify if team project collection database is broken

```
USE {Tfs_CollectionName}
GO
select * from sys.extended_properties
```

TFS_SERVICE_LEVEL property must exist and value for that property must be set in order to perform upgrade.